# Select and NgModel issue with model

Tags: angularjs, select, angular-ngmodel

I have an issue with select tag and ngmodel. The value of the variable in the model is not represented in the options in the dropdown.

Here is the code:

```
<select ng-model="number">
  <option values="5">5</option>
  <option values="10">10</option>
  <option values="20">20</option>
  <option values="25">25</option>
</select>
```

Where `number` is defined in controller as 20.

After the compilation, the following HTML is added:

```
<option value="? undefined:undefined ?"></option>
```

NOTE:

I also presented `number` in the HTML view, and it has no problem with showing the number in the expression `{{number}}` - it is then displayed correctly.

Here is a plnkr:

http://plnkr.co/edit/IXfwByE5ZrA4y7z0y6mh?p=preview

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Do you want an extra option that displays the value of `number`?

Comment: do you have ` $scope.number = '20';` in controller? [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/abpMtEFKTrU3f7MzJvrv?p=preview)

Comment: @LJ.Wizard exactly, I want selected option (the one that is seelcted by default) to be the value of $scope.number

Comment: As long as you are able to see the value {{number}} in the view then there is no problem with ngModel. Please provide plunker url by replicating your problem.

Comment: @klski, in my controller, I have it as number, to as a string.

Comment: you're welcome by the way (plnkr) .. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this way

```
<select name="mydata" ng-model="number" 
    ng-options="value for value in [5,10,20,25]">
</select>
```

in Controller

```
$scope.number = 20;
```

Comment: It works like that. Do you know why it doesn't work in case when I dont use ng-options?

Comment: I think because option value can only take value string so if you put $scope.number = '20'; then you html will work. otherwise you need to use ng-options

Answer (score 1):

> If the viewValue of ngModel does not match any of the options, then
>   the control will automatically add an "unknown" option, which it then
>   removes when the mismatch is resolved.

documentation [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select)

Normally, angular will make an option selected, if the  model's value matches with the value of one of the options.

10 is of value 10 and data type string where as your $scope.number = 10 makes it's value 10 of number type.

So model's value is mismatched.

Try $scope.number = '10' in your controller and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

You have **$scope.number=5**. You should have

```
$scope.number = '5'   // a string. Change 5 to '5'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.number = 5+"";
```

Add this statement in your controller instead of $scope.number=5 because value for option is string